# Similarity of two audio signals according to the human ear

Tags: waveform-similarity

Let's say I have two different real signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in the auditory range of humans. What differences in properties of these signals would be minimized for these two signals to sound approximately same to a human ear?

I'm looking to use this to find the closest match $\hat{x}(t)$ to a given sample $y(t)$, but ignoring anything explicitly musical like key/time signature, rhythm, or BPM. $y(t)$ is probably closer to a gregorian chant or choral music than a pop or dance song. (This isn't a question about shazam-style fingerprinting: candidates $x(t)$ do not include $y(t)$.)

Some ideas that operate on a sequence of overlapping time windows along these signals:

- Sum of squares of the difference in power of each window.
- FFT each window into non-uniform frequency bins matching human audio resolution, and then take the sum over each bin for each window of the squared difference in magnitude.

Are these sensible? Are there better approaches? A search for `similarity` finds posts mentioning [cross-correlation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18651/similarity-between-two-signals-cycle-by-cycle) and [coherence](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/22581/65487) but it's not clear to me that these are how humans tell two audio samples apart.